# Salesforrce: JavaScript Remoting "Uncaught ReferenceError: Visualforce is not defined"

Tags: javascript, salesforce, remoting, visualforce, force.com

I'm using JavaScript Remoting in my Force.com site.  This works well apart from a scenario I have noted where when I click on an `apex:commandLink` or `apex:commandButton` in a component which then opens my component where my JavaScript remoting function exists, when I then try to perform my Remoting action I get an error as follows.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Visualforce is not defined
```

I do not get this error when I do not previously click on am `apex:CommandLink` or `apex:commandButton` in a previous component.  Has anyone come across this before & if so know how to stop the error from occurring?

Comment: Hi all, Using a controller extension as suggested in http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Winter-12-breaks-JS-Remoting/td-p/336947/page/2 resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Visual Force Page (VFP).  In your VFP definition, make sure to include the controller that has the methods for JS remoting

```
<apex:page controller="YourController" ... />
```